# Body parts disconnected after rigging

Tags: animation, rigging, vertices, weight-painting, parent

I have tried everything within my limited reach to fix this issue, however as I parent this body I imported as an fbx from Character Creator and an armature I got from DeepMotion with automatic weights, certain body parts (eyes, teeth, tongue etc.) get deformed and don't move in accordance with the rest of the body after I switch from rest position to pose position of the armature.

What I have tried so far: Parenting those body parts individually with automatic weights, rigging with Auto Rig Pro, merging the body meshes, weight painting (totally haphazardly since I have no clue how to do it right).

Blender file (before parenting the body and the armature): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uI5m1pEl2IT64m0VF-qBSxtrlPDMmlbn/view?usp=sharing

How do I fix it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*My guess is that there is no corresponding "bone" in the armature that I could connect those body parts to. However there has to be a solution?*

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As Blunder says, first scale up the *head_JNT* bone, which is very tiny for the moment.

Then parent the body to the armature *With Automatic Weight*. The mouth and eyes are separated objects, you can join them to the rest of the body with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

In *Edit* mode, select the mouth and the eyes with <kbd>L</kbd> and in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the vertex groups they should be part of (*head_JNT*) and click on the *Assign* button under the vertex groups list.

For the eyelashes (again thanks to Blunder), remove the mesh from all groups (down arrow button on the right of the vertex groups list) and assign to *head_JNT*.

In order to test the parenting I switched back the armature to *Pose* mode, and as it had an action I closed the action in the *Dope Sheet > Action Editor*.

Comment: The armature has a head bone. It's called *head_JNT* and it's so tiny that it's hidden in the ball of neck bone. Just scale it up. The eyelashes are included in the body mesh. Automatic weights don't work well for them, You need to assign them manually to the *head_JNT* vertex group and remove them from all other groups (drop-down menu of the vertex group menu).

Comment: oh ok I didn't see the head bone and the eyelash problem, thanks

Comment: I can't explain in words how thankful I am for your quick fix. I tried adding new bones for the tongue and eye parts but then I couldn't get the eyelashes attached. Thank you guys so much!!